# React Redux form text field initial value not being set

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to set an initial value / default value for a text field in Redux Form:

```
const RegisterForm = ({ handleSubmit, pristine, submitting }) => (

    <form className="ui form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="field">
            <Field
                component="input"
                type="text"
                name="email"
                placeholder="E-mail Address"
                className="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
            <Field
                component="input"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                className="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="field">
            <Field
                component="input"
                type="text"
                name="inviteCode"
                defaultValue="default"
                placeholder="Invite Code (Optional)"
                className="form-control" />
        </div>
        <Button type="btn btn-default" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
            Register
        </Button>

        <p className="login-text">Already have an account? </p>
        <a href="/">Log in</a>
    </form>
);


RegisterForm.propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    pristine: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'registerForm',
    initialValues: {
        inviteCode: 'Test'
    }
})(RegisterForm);
```

Here is where I'm setting the initial value:

```
initialValues: {
    inviteCode: 'Test'
}
```

This does nothing to my `inviteCode` field, it does not show any value. I get no errors in the console either.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to set `enableReinitialize : true` for my form:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'registerForm',
    initialValues: {
        inviteCode: 'Test'
    },
    enableReinitialize : true
})(RegisterForm);
```